# this is about formal specification

Tags: logical-operators

Consider the following predicates defined over the domain of vegetables:

```
R(x) : x is a root vegetable
T(x) : x tastes nice
```

Additionally the proposition `P` is defined as:

```
P : Peas are blue
```

Now express the following statements symbolically:

1. If peas are blue then cabbage tastes nice.
2. There exists a root vegetable that tastes nice.
3. Lettuce is a root vegetable and peas are blue.
4. All root vegetables taste nice.
5. Peas are blue or there is a vegetable which is a root vegetable and which does not taste nice.

Comment: Sorry, but it sounds like homework to do.

Comment: no it only that we are arguing with my friend so we wanted to see maybe if you have a different answer

Comment: @real-ars well in that case keep in mind that logic is not always the best weapon for winning an argument, cf. Schopenhauer's [The art of being right](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Being_Right)

Answer (score 0):

Predicate logic is fun ;)

```
P ⇒ (∀x Cabbage(x) ⇒ T(x))
∃x R(x) ⇒ T(x)
∀x (Lettuce(x) ⇒ R(x)) ∧ P
∀x R(x) ⇒ T(x)
P ∨ (∃x R(x) ∧ ¬T(x))
```